# Mechanism to prevent edits without approval?

Tags: discussion, edits

I would say a quarter to half my questions end up getting edited the vast majority of which end up dramatically changing the context of my question. I'm not against good advice (I've acted on about 2% of all the criticisms I have ever had about my work since they were actually thoughtful) though I think since I joined overflow sites years after I've had a good grip on most of the material I work with people are seeing low reputation and presuming that equates to low levels of comprehension.

Regardless of the reasoning behind people making edits is there an option I can use that would require my approval in order to commit an edit to my questions?

- I have no interest in spamming questions in order to artificially boost my reputation.
- I am getting tired of having to add bullet points telling people to ask for clarifications instead of editing my posts.
- Having to correct my posts so often reduces my desire to ask the question if I have to review the question again (even with the revision pages available).
- As this is a discussion there is no reason to edit this post, I will be happy to revise my own if you leave comments as I actively follow questions I participate in though the office of redundancy redundancy requires that I state I know what I am asking.

For example, say I post about Kubuntu (which by default uses KDE) and someone edits it changing the OS to Ubuntu (which uses Gnome by default). Then, answers become Gnome-oriented for a KDE question and the entire context has been changed--negating the point of asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Editing is part of SO and SE. Whatever your level of rep. I still get edited on ELU and I'm highly active there

Comment: If you find that your content is frequently edited, perhaps you are indeed the "problem." Term used loosely, not intended to condemn, imply less-than-favored status or anything else that could be inferred as an intention of being rude, particularly in the snark-free zone that is Stack Overflow, MSO, and SE.

Comment: @simchona yup; I am at 17.7k, and made it to the final round of the recent mod election, and still get edited. :)

Comment: Your new last sentence is a run on.

Comment: You have a bit over 100 posts on Stack Overflow and a bit over 600 reputation earned there (allowing for the two bounties). Now there is nothing wrong with that, but it is also not particularly high either (a bit less than one vote for post as you're running a pretty even question/answer split). I suspect that *something* you are doing troubles or confuses your audience. Add that to frequent edits and you may want to consider what you could do "better". Also, I figure that on order of 80% of the edits people make to my posts improve them.

Comment: I just spent several minutes looking at your SO questions, and I could barely find any that were edited by others, and those I did see did little more than some formatting and adding a tag. Could you provide some links to demonstrate what you're talking about?

Comment: Browsing through some of your posts, I feel that Ubuntu thing must have been an exception. Any other examples like that? And as an aside: no need to add tags to your titles. (Like: "jQuery: something".)

Comment: Just a comment on editing this post: why should people have to post a comment "your last sentence is too long, so fix it like this" when they can just get the ball rolling a fix it themselves? It slows everything down.

Answer (score 7):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Other people can edit my posts?!
>
> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!
>
> All edits are tracked in a public revision history. To view revisions, click the edit date on the post.
>
> **If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.**

Comment: And this also wants me to remove statements like *"As this is a discussion there is no reason to edit this post"*!

Answer (score 2):

If you feel an edit was *wrong* in the sense of shifting the focus of your question to something completely different, then roll it back.

If you have a question about Kubuntu and someone edits it to Ubuntu, then obviously that's *not* what you intended and it certainly won't help you get better answers — even worse, it might get you the wrong answers for your actual problem.

Edits should always *improve* a post, so if it made your question worse, roll it back. You should have the final say here. Maybe ping the editor with a comment below your post to tell them why you don't approve of the edit.

However, if an edit was made in good faith to fix formatting or spelling errors, or clarify your post altogether, then by no means should it be rolled back without a good reason.